# How to reset jquery wait cursor after form load?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this code in the master page  (using Ajax Update Panel) which turns into a wait swirl after submitting

```
$("form").submit(function () {
     $("*").css("cursor", "wait");
});
```

However that swirl reappears whenever cursor is moved to some parts outside of divs.

I was hoping this would reset cursor after the grid has been loaded

```
$("form").load(function () {
     $("*").css('cursor', 'auto');
});
```

But it does not. Is there any simple way of achieving this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UpdatePanel have their javascript function to signaling the partial update, and the end of it, and so your code can be as:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
       prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
       prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
    });        

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {       
       $("*").css("cursor", "wait");
    }

    function EndRequest(sender, args) {       
       $("*").css('cursor', 'auto');
    }
</script>
```